# CSS on :target stays on even after changing location.hash

Tags: javascript, css

I use /page/#hash to go to

```
 <div id="hash" class="list-recipe"></div>
 <style>
 /* which I highlight using this */
 .list-recipe:target{ border:2px solid red; }
 </style>
```

How can I remove the style using javascript?

Because changing location.hash doesn't work and changing URL dynamically also doesn't.

---

Example:
https://www.halladays.com/recipes/desserts/#peaches-cream-cheesecake

Then click on other recipe title -> it will change the location.hash, but the styling for :target stays on.

How can I remove it?

Comment: The hash did not change. I assume it would work if the other link was  `https://www.halladays.com/recipes/desserts#chocolate-peanut-butter-cup-cheesecake`

Comment: I found hotfix for this, you need to replace `.list-recipe:target, .targeted{` with `.list-recipe.targeted{`

Comment: also as mentioned before you don't have any `#` in your url, that may be the ussie

Comment: @stetoc I can't remove it, it's there for a reason, but thanks for checking it out. Changing location.hash doesn't work either.